# Pin tab does not work in Safari, after creating tab groups

Tags: safari, tabs

I created a tab group in Safari and added a few tabs to it.

It does not give me an option to pin a tab in the tab group.

How do I pin tabs in a tab group?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer; **there is no way to see your Pinned Tabs while using Tab Groups**

I think it sucks. I pin tabs like calendar, todo lists, instant messages, etc. These are exactly the things that I want to be able to access from anywhere and everywhere.

Overall I think that Safari's approach to the window/pinned tabs/tab groups/tabs hierarchy is very different compared to other browsers... but not in any good ways.

### Similar discussions

I just switched back to using Safari after Brave was crashing on me continuously, and I found this to be a noticeable shortcoming straight away.

I went Googling and found these other discussions which suggest that Apple sort of considers Tab Groups and Pinned Tabs to be overlapping features:

- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253203242
- https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/safari-15-no-pinned-tabs-in-tab-groups.2312407

Bad call imo, hope they consider changing how the pinned tabs work

Answer (score 0):

Since it's not clear which device you're using, and since the other answer is for Mac, I'll post the answer for iPhone and iPad.

### iPhone and iPad

You can do this on both iPhone and iPad.

From [Organize your tabs with Tab Groups in Safari on iPhone](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/iphone/iph3028ebf68/ios):

> #### Pin a tab at the top of a Tab Group
>
> You can customize your Tab Groups with pinned tabs in each group. The pinned tab stays at the top of the Tab Group.
>
> 1. Tap [image: the Tabs button] to view the open tabs in that Tab Group.
> 2. Touch and hold the tab you want to pin.
> 3. In the menu that appears, tap Pin Tab.

[image] [image]

<sup>(Click images to open full size)</sup>

From [Organize your tabs with Tab Groups in Safari on iPad](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/ipad/ipadf5a4dd79/ipados):

> #### Pin a tab at the front of a Tab Group
>
> You can customize your Tab Groups with pinned tabs in each group. The pinned tab stays pinned to the left side of the tab bar.
>
> 1. Touch and hold the tab you want to pin.
> 2. In the menu that appears, tap Pin Tab.
>
> To unpin the tab, touch and hold it, then tap Unpin Tab.

[image]

[image]

<sup>(Click images to open full size)</sup>